# CSS arrow cut on div or box container

Tags: html, css

How can we achieve this one? from simple square menu to this -> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReUHe.jpg)

Here's my simple css

.menu {

```
width:50px;
height:50px;
display:block;
background-color:red;
overflow:hidden
-ms-transform: skew(-30deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: skew(-30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: skew(-30deg); /* Standard syntax */
```

}

I only got an incline instead

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow, can you also share a screenshot perhaps of your expected vs actual layout? and also share the html scripts of the said display.

Comment: Hello there, kindly see this screenshot -> https://ibb.co/SPRVQbs .. so basically the left side is the actual rendered using elementor, and on the right side, it's a mock design which is the goal here.. to make looks like that.. here's the sample code from Elementor -> https://ibb.co/BCRLqf7

Answer (score -1):

```
column-2::before {
 background-image: url('screen background image');
 border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
 border-left: 25px solid #85c8ea;
 border-top: 20px solid transparent;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

Comment: need to cut the whole container or column box just like this one sir - https://ibb.co/Yy7wNn0